# Can't freeze flask web site inside giltab ci

Tags: python-3.x, flask, yaml, gitlab-ci-runner

I have the flask app example file, demo_app.py

I want the html site that is build by flask to be frozen so that I can pick it up for later usage.

The problem is that using "- flask run" on the .gitlab-ci.yml will stop any subsequent tasks:

```
* Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
```

this is the python code (basic flask example):

```
from flask import Flask

mi_app = Flask(__name__)

@my_app.route('/')
def index():
    package = """
    <html>
    <h2>some html code here</h2>
    </html>
    """
    return(package)
'''
```

this is the gitlab-ci.yml code:

```
image: "python:3.7"

stages:
    - Install
    - Deploy

cache:
    key: apt-cache
    paths:
        - apt-cache/

before_script:
    - echo "starting ${CI_JOB_STAGE}"

Construir:
    stage: Install
    except:
        - master
    tags:
        - python
    script:
        #- |
        - echo -e 'deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic main universe deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security main universe deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates main universe' >> /etc/apt/sources.list
        - apt-key adv --recv-keys --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com 40976EAF437D05B5
        - apt-key adv --recv-keys --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com 3B4FE6ACC0B21F32
        - apt-get -qq update
        - python3.7 --version
        - apt-get install python3-pip -y
        #- python demo_app.py test

Deployar:
    stage: Deploy
    except:
        - master
    tags:
        - python
    script:
        - pip3 install flask
        - pip3 install Frozen-Flask
        - export FLASK_APP=demo_app.py
        #- while [[ "$(curl -s -o /dev/null -w ''%{http_code}'' localhost:5000)" != "200" ]]; do sleep 5; done &
        - python3 -m demo_app.py
        - pwd
        - ls -al
        #- cd build
        #- cat index.html
```

I've tried the following approaches:

1. running flask-frozen "inside" the demo_app.py and avoid using flask run on the yml. Got this:

$ python3 -m demo_app.py
/usr/local/bin/python3: Error while finding module specification for 'demo_app.py' (ModuleNotFoundError: **path** attribute not found on 'demo_app' while trying to find 'demo_app.py')

2. using a while loop for curl waiting for flask run to launch, but as I said it stoped on Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit) and can't continue

I expect having a way to use flask run inside the gitlab-ci.yml and let my gitlab pipeline to automatically continue through the steps running until it hits the flask-frozen stage to freeze the web site.

Another approach different than this is also appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: You don't have to run your app to use frozen.

Comment: thx! so, I've used it in this way and still no luck: from flask import Flask
from flask_frozen import Freezer

mi_app = Flask(__name__)
freezer = Freezer(mi_app)

@mi_app.cli.command()
def freeze():
    freezer.freeze()

@mi_app.route('/')

Answer (score 0):

pyton -m doesn't want .py. After removing it worked fine.